# Possible to have SearchCenter as standalone site connected to Intranet Portal?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm building a new Intranet Portal with SharePoint 2007 that will have News, Site Directory, and Search.  Because I want to invest some serious time into customizing and tuning search, I would like to learn whether it is possible to have the Intranet Search live in its own top-level site collection?  That would allow me to isolate and back up/recover the Enterprise Search site independantly of the Portal.

So my question is whether this is doable and if so, how do I connect the Intranet Portal site collection to use my seperate Search site when users execute searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Create a Search Center Site Collection. Then in all other site collections go to site settings and the using Search settings (under site collection settings header) point to where your search center is.

Comment: Thanks, I found that this works great for standard Team Sites.  However for my Intranet Portal that uses the Collaboration Portal template, the scopes dropdown still only has "This Site: xxx" in it and I can't seem to get the scopes to display from the Search Center.  I do see that the link for Advanced Search goes now to the new Search site collection which is good.  Any thoughts?

Comment: you can set the allowed scopes also in the site-settings of your portal.

Comment: Go to site collection settings and in search settings you need to change it to allow custom scopes.